# login v.qq.com using htmlunit

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

I want to login [**v.qq.com**](https://v.qq.com/) using JAVA. I could login v.qq.com using **selenium**, but for some reason i have to give up this way (selenium required a chrome driver which needs GTK and many stuff on remote server). Then I try [**htmlunit**](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), and it works on other video website but not on this v.qq.com :(

selenium version: 3.0.1 
htmlunit version: 2.24

Here is my selenium and htmlunit code. The selenium function works on my computer while htmlunit does not. Hopes for some help...

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Test {

    public static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String user = "3245845924";
        String pass = "yoyo123456";
//        Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> cookies = selenium(user, pass);// success: 30+ Cookie
        Set<com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie> cookies = htmlunit(user, pass);// fail: only 13 Cookie
        System.out.println(cookies);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(cookies));
        System.out.println(cookies.size());
    }

    public static Set<com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie> htmlunit(String user, String pass) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://xui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/xlogin?appid=532001601&s_url=https%3A//v.qq.com";// also tried https
        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);// BEST_SUPPORTED=CHROME, also tried FIREFOX_45, EDGE, INTERNET_EXPLORER and FIREFOX_38
        client.setJavaScriptTimeout(1000 * 30);
        client.getOptions().setTimeout(1000 * 30);
//        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);// also tried this
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
//        client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());// also tried this
        HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000 * 20);
//        page = page.getElementById("switcher_plogin").click();
        HtmlInput userElement = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("u");
        userElement.type(user);// also tried setValueAttribute function
        HtmlInput passElement = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("p");
        passElement.type(pass);
        HtmlElement loginElement = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("login_button");
        System.out.println(client.getCookieManager().getCookies());
        System.out.println(client.getCookieManager().getCookies().size());// size: 11
        HtmlPage page2 = loginElement.click();
        client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000 * 30);
        System.out.println(client.getCookieManager().getCookies());
        System.out.println(client.getCookieManager().getCookies().size());// size: 13
        client.close();
        return client.getCookieManager().getCookies();
    }

    public static Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> selenium(String user, String pass) throws InterruptedException {
        String url = "https://xui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/xlogin?appid=532001601&&s_url=https%3A//v.qq.com";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/tmp/chromedriver");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        WebElement element = driver.findElementById("switcher_plogin");
        element.click();
        element = driver.findElementById("u");
        element.click();
        driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(user);
        element = driver.findElementById("p");
        element.click();
        driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(pass);
        element = driver.findElementById("login_button");
        element.click();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        Set<org.openqa.selenium.Cookie> ret = driver.manage().getCookies();
//        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());// success, go to home page, title: 腾讯视频-中国领先的在线视频媒体平台,海量高清视频在线观看
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

There is some log while using htmlunit. I think it might help (although I can't understand these log):

```
2017-01-29 19:15:45,402 [org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies]-[WARN] Cookie rejected [pt_user_id="10515554044972903633", version:0, domain:ui.ptlogin2.qq.com, path:/, expiry:Wed Jan 27 19:15:45 CST 2027] Illegal 'domain' attribute "ui.ptlogin2.qq.com". Domain of origin: "xui.ptlogin2.qq.com"
2017-01-29 19:15:45,406 [org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies]-[WARN] Cookie rejected [ptui_identifier="000DF936CD35D39B19CDD2C005A3FF6C0CF1D3AF4EAD04B9B4EC43F3", version:0, domain:ui.ptlogin2.qq.com, path:/, expiry:null] Illegal 'domain' attribute "ui.ptlogin2.qq.com". Domain of origin: "xui.ptlogin2.qq.com"
2017-01-29 19:15:46,312 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl]-[WARN] Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
2017-01-29 19:15:46,677 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl]-[WARN] Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
2017-01-29 19:15:47,371 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler]-[WARN] CSS error: 'http://xui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/xlogin?appid=532001601&s_url=http%3A//v.qq.com' [1:4914] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "+". Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <S>, <IDENT>, "}", ";", "*".)
2017-01-29 19:15:47,371 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler]-[WARN] CSS warning: 'http://xui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/xlogin?appid=532001601&s_url=http%3A//v.qq.com' [1:4914] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
2017-01-29 19:15:47,735 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl]-[WARN] Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
2017-01-29 19:15:48,166 [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl]-[WARN] Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
```

**--- update 2017.01.30 ---**

Finally, I login v.qq.com successfully through another login link, though I use phantomjs instead of HtmlUnit. You can see this link in the comment(need 10+ reputation to post more links).

but I still can't understand these log :(

Comment: The first two log entries are locking like something you have to analyze (Illegal 'domain' attribute "ui.ptlogin2.qq.com". Domain of origin: "xui.ptlogin2.qq.com") Please try to figure out if the real browsers are reverting this cookie also. If not please open an issue against HtmlUnit.

Comment: @RBRi I found that [this login link](https://xui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/xlogin?appid=532001601&s_url=https%3A//v.qq.com) doesn't give me the cookie 'pt_user_id' or 'ptui_identifier' directly.But when I visit [another login url](https://ui.ptlogin2.qq.com/cgi-bin/login?style=9&appid=532001601&s_url=https%3A//v.qq.com&low_login=0), this link give me both 'pt_user_id' and 'ptui_identifier' (and domain='ui.ptlogin2.qq.com')